# What is a word for making fun of someone that's learning or new at something?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives

With as many word suggestions as possible, what words can you use to describe *a person who makes fun of someone for being new to something or learning*?

Like for example, being shamed for asking questions or riding a bike for the first time or making a mistake or just not understanding something yet
Ignorance comes to mind but it's not specific enough..

Please help me out

Comment: You need one: an asshole.

Comment: Silly or childish behaviour.

Comment: Jerk: a contemptibly obnoxious person.

Comment: Only an idiot does that.

Comment: Answers that contain a list of words are *not* encouraged on EL&U. You can use a thesaurus any time you want! :) How would you, the OP, choose which answer is the best if there is no detail, no explanation and no links?

Answer (score 3):

Consider **mocking**:

> showing that you think **someone** or something **is** **stupid**

([Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/mocking))

Or **sneerer**:

> sneerer: a person who **expresses contempt by remarks** or facial expression

([WordNet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=sneerer))

Depending on the context, [**elitist**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=elitist) might fit as well. An elitist community may flaunt its superiority by being unfriendly or mean to newcomers (hence sneer at their questions, ridicule, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

A number of words (besides the fine ones suggested by A.P., above):

> - supercilious
> - belittling
> - contemptuous
> - arrogant
> - unkind
> - overweening
> - condescending
> - haughty
> - snob, or snobbish
> - pompous
> - pretentious
> - highfalutin
> - uppity
> - imperious
> - high and mighty
> - stuck-up
> - overbearing

Some of the above words are better and/or more apt than others, but they could be fleshed out with more context, additional descriptors, and a scenario.

Answer (score 0):

***haze***:
*to subject (freshmen, newcomers, etc.) to abusive or humiliating tricks and ridicule.*

***hazer***:
*a person or thing that hazes.*